# Windows Phone 7 - Setting style for specific control within selected ListBoxItem

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, styles, datatemplate

let's say i have something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="list" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SomeItem, Mode=TwoWay}">                    
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="first" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="second" Text="{Binding OtherProperty}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Now, how do i alter some style property (f.ex. FontSize) of *only* the TextBlock called "second" when a ListBoxItem gets selected? If i'd like to set the FontSize for all ListBoxItem's contents, then i'd have no problem. That scenario is quite well documented here and elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 6):

I will not give you an exact solution, but a good point to start with: check out the file

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\vX.Y\Design\System.Windows.xaml
```

you have to adjust X.Y to 7.0/7.1 along with your setup. There you will find exactly the same Control-Templates that are being used all the basic UI Controls of the WP7/Silverlight. Open it in VisualStudio-or-whateverelse and search for:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  (... and immediatelly following ~40 lines of xaml)
```

ah well, since I've opened that file, here's that

```
    <!--x:Key="PhoneListBoxItem"-->
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                  <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
            </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This is the complete style for your **DEFAULT** ListBoxItem - the thing you want to alter. Skim through the code and note the 'ContentPresenter' and preceding 'VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates"'.

ContentPresenter is the thing that will show your DataTemplate for the item.
VisualStates in that group define the *changes* from the *normal* state that should occur if a "selected state" is fired of on an list element.
Once the "selection state" diminishes, the element returns to the unselected state automatically and his visuals follow. Note also that the Unselected visual state does not enforce any changes - so it preserves your plain DataTemplate style.

The last thing to notice is that this is a style for ListBoxItem, and *not* for your data-item, nor your data-template. Your DataTemplate is never touched, it is directly displayed by the ContentPresenter. The ListBox wraps all your items in "ListBoxItem" instances, then displays those ListBoxItems and applies that style to them.

IMHO, this is the point you will have to work with.

You may want to copy&alter this style to your needs, and then set your *ListBox.ItemContainerStyle* to that *new* style. One of the ways is:

```
<YourPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="mylistboxitemoverride" .....
        ........
    </Style>
</YourPage.Resources>
...
...
<ListBox ......... ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource mylistboxitemoverride}"
    ...
    ...
</ListBox>
```

Now, the trick is to modify the 'Selected' VisualState, and make it alter not the Foreground (doing that would restyle both your TextBoxes!), but some other property which will affect only one of your txbs. Unfortunatelly, that may be harder/uglier. I don't at that moment any idea how to make it "prettier" than hard-replacing the ContentPresenter with your DataTemplate and referencing your exact leaf-textbox in the VisualState like that:

```
    <Style .... TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                  <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SECOND" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".5" /> <!-- #### RETARGETTED -->
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SECOND" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"> <!-- #### RETARGETTED -->
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

              <!-- #### INLINED YOUR DATATEMPLATE -->
              <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          DataContext="{TemplateBinding Content}">  <!-- #### careful with the bindings. the DataCtx may be needed or is spurious. do check that! -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" />  <!-- #### referenced from nowhere, so I removed the name -->
                <TextBlock x:Name="SECOND" Text="{Binding OtherProperty}" />
              </StackPanel>

            </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This should be almost what you want, or at least very close to it. I have not tested it, you may need to tinker with proper data-binding (I've included a DataContent=binding:Content, but that's a quick guess) and probably you will want to add your own animations. I think you have now tons of bits to experiment with. Have fun!

Comment: Wow, this looks pretty definitive :-O I'm currently busy on an another part of the app, but i'll definitely try this out in a few days!

Comment: Can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680751/longlistselector-with-list-item-selection-style/22706935?noredirect=1#22706935

Answer (score 0):

Set the Style on the TextBlock to a Style that does what you want.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock x:Name="first" Style="{StaticResource Header}" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
   <TextBlock x:Name="second" Style="{StaticResource Info}" Text="{Binding OtherProperty}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: ..except that it will work globally on all items in their normal state, and the author asks for alteration of selected state

Answer (score 0):

one way to achieve this is, create an extended ListBox class with a SecondText dependency property in it. Then just use Blend to generate a normal ListBox style, change the targat type to my ExtendedListBox.

In this style, add another TextBlock control and set its Text TemplateBinding to the SecondText. You just need to alter this TextBlock's font size in the selected visual state.

Also, rather than extending the ListBox, you might be able to create an attached property SecondText and just TemplateBinding to it directly, but I haven't tested this method yet.

Hope this can get you started with. :)

Comment: hm.. why are you suggesting altering the ListBox, when the problem relates to the ListBoxItem's templates? The @juarola wanted to alter the 'selected state' visuals so that only the second tbox gets restyled (ie. highlighted) upon selecting an item

Comment: sorry i did mean ListBoxItem, but having thought of this again, it's actually easier to take juarola's suggestion to do it in the ListBoxItem style. sorry for the confusion, i am embarrassed, :(