# Windows Phone 7 dev: How highlight selection of ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have this code in my .xaml file

```
<ListBox Name="Tracks" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding AllTracks}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="150">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,-3,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Album}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,3,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

I put data in my list like that(MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
                Tracks.ItemsSource = library.Songs;).
I can see data on my list but when i select something, the selection doesn't highlighted,
how i can fix it? Thanks...

Comment: I expect that the phone styles don't use a highlight colour in the Selected visual state. You could try a different non-phone style to check.

Comment: Indeed, it uses PhoneAccentBrush

Answer (score 3):

The phone applies the Accent colour as Foreground to the selected element's VisualTree. But since you're overriding the style for all the elements, it's likely that the colour won't be applied.

Try with a regular TextBlock without any Style, and you'll see.

Comment: ok thanks, i tried without style an it works, now do you know how i can change the color of the selection?

Comment: @Tim The colour used is the accent colour. To use a custom one, create a new style for the listbox in Blend and change the highlight color to whatever you like.

Comment: ok, thanks there is any way to change color of the background (stackPanel i think) , when i select something?

Comment: See this guide http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Templating-Controls-with-Silverlight-Silverlight-TV-36

Answer (score 0):

Here: [Windows Phone 7 - Setting style for specific control within selected ListBoxItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340880/windows-phone-7-setting-style-for-specific-control-within-selected-listboxitem/7359024#7359024) I've written a bit in response to a similar problem. Please read at least the original post/problem and my answer to it. It may look overwhelming at first as there's not a small amount of extra XAML, but in fact it is quite easy to follow and once you look at it as a several different aspects (template, styles, visualstates) - it turns out to be .. quite short, paradoxically. Once you read through it, you will probably notice that your problem is almost exactly the same, with the minor difference that the 'animated' property/target from foreground of textbox to a background of the panel..