# LongListSelector with list item selection style

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

I am working on Windows Phone 8 and i have Longlist selector with few item in it.

I am using the below code for highlighting the selected item in the list box.But i want the same effect to be achieved for LongListSelector.

How to do it ?

```
<Style x:Key="ListItemSelectorStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property ="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Border x:Name="ListBoxItem" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" 
                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ListItemBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#c9ebf2" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ListItemBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#c9ebf2" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                <Border x:Name="ListItemBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#FFFFFF">
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" 
                                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I try your code, but [the LongListSelector control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) display a list of selectable items with a mechanism for users to jump to a specific section of the list. This is the [sample code](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/05/23/windows-phone-8-xaml-longlistselector.aspx).

But if you want achieved the effect like **ListBox**, you can set the template

```
<Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Seleced">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportControl">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ViewportControl x:Name="ViewportControl" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4,0,4,0" Opacity="0" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

Comment: Where do i need to add this template ?

Comment: @user3114009, Add within <Style x:Key="LongListSelectorStyle1" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector"></Style>

Comment: Yes i added that and also i have added Style="{StaticResource LongListSelectorStyle1}" to my <phone:LongListSelector  but nothing happens when i select the item, i mean its not highlighting the selected item

Comment: "Seleced" should be "Selected" in the template.