# How do I specify they style of a selected ListBoxItem in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Currently when I select an item in a list it sets the item to have a blue background. I'm trying to specify that a list item should have no background at all, i.e. be transparent, when it's selected.

So far, I have my ListBox defined as:

```
<ListBox Name="LogsListBox" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

but it's still appearing as blue when I select a list item.

What do I need to do to make the list item transparent when selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer and it worked:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359024/181771

Basically I pasted this into my UserControl:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" 
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" 
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"  
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a brush defined somewhere in your project with the name "ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush", like so:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF4617B4" />
```

If not, define a new one, in your application resource dictionnary.